# Having trouble with connecting to MySQL database in php HOSTING

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I am hosting my php website Warning occur :

Warning:mysql_connect()[function_mysql_connect]: Access denied for user'gazebostudio'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your db credentials are correct. If you host database remotely, you may need to change db host name accordingly So 'localhost' won't work there.

If above settings are ok check whether the particular user has been granted proper privileges.